# Birth Records for Orhei/Orgeev from 1881

Tags: birth-records, russia, jewish, bessarabia

I am searching for the birth record of **Elias Weinstock** who was born in Orhei in 1881.  Where is the best resource to search for `Orhei` birth records.  I have tried all the usual sources however I cannot find any record of the `Weinstock` family in this area.

Answer (score 3):

[Orhei/Orgeev](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orhei) is a town in Moldova, which was formerly part of Bessarabia / the Russian Empire / Romania / the Moldavian SSR. Orhei has an English translation of its [history](https://www.orhei.md/index.php?pag=page&id=866&l=en) page, so you can see approximately when it was part of which nation.

If your target person, Elias Weinstock, was Jewish, you might find some helpful information on FamilySearch's [Finding Jewish Ancestors in Moldova](https://www.familysearch.org/en/wiki/Finding_Jewish_Ancestors_in_Moldova) page.

That page mentions Miriam Weiner's [*Jewish Roots in Ukraine and Moldova*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jewish_Roots_in_Ukraine_and_Moldova), published in 1999 through the Routes to Roots Foundation.

The Routes to Roots Foundation also has a [searchable database](https://www.rtrfoundation.org/search.php). If you plug in `Orhei`, you may or may not find any towns in the database, but if you plug in `starts with "Or"` there are several types of documents for the town of **Orgeyev** in **Moldova**.

I have looked at the RTR database only briefly, so you'll want to read its help pages to figure out how to use it properly, but that may give you a start.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking - besides Elias - to **ANY** `Weinstock` records from `Orhei, Moldova`

Then here is what I found:

**1**. [JewishGen's burial database](https://www.jewishgen.org/databases/cemetery/) - 9 Weinstock burial records from Orhei, Moldova

[image]

**2**. Ancestry has a profile of a Nicole - that has a family tree containing Weinstocks from Orhei

[image]

[image]